# Script from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I create script from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2012.

When I run that script on SQL Server 2012, the database is created, but there is error for this line

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION` is [indeed new in 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but what's your question?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012 you can set MAXDOP  at instance level (your example is from SQL Server 2016 where you could do this on database level).